# Obtaining Hispanic Population % from Google Maps Demographics Layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are using the Google Maps API for Business and are leveraging the Demographics Layer for shading the map areas.

Looking at the [data fields](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/demographics#data_fields) there are a number of metrics that breakdown the population by race as a %. A category for Latin American/Hispanic is glaringly missing. There is a category for "other_race", but it seems odd that the Latin American/Hispanic value would get lumped into that.

Anyone have an idea if this is an oversight by Google or something that can be confidently derived given the data provided?

Comment: As you have Business licence help from Google is part of the agreement.

Comment: Yep. Have a case logged. Thought the community might know something too.

Answer (score 0):

I've been into this for around a year now. What I had to do was import the polygons from the census page and do it all myself manually.  Not sure why they left out hispanic data.

Answer (score 0):

The census does not include Hispanic as a race but as an ethnicity. The actual census data includes a breakdown of race by ethnicity. This appears not to have been incorporated into google's map data.