# Google Maps API - Demographic Layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, demographics

My question is in regards to accessing demographic information through google maps api.

I can not find publicly available documentation for the "google maps demographics layer". Google does advertise that it has such a product, under google maps for business or enterprise https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oF4uCJ6EDZo . And I did find one other developer who is using this feature at his project [Obtaining Hispanic Population % from Google Maps Demographics Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16485893) - but the link he referred to was inaccessible. I guess that this is a feature only available to customers who have purchased the required google maps plans?

I need to confirm that such a feature exists and we have a known way to get access to the feature.

I am building a program that takes a list of addresses and places markers on each address. When a specific property marker (address) is clicked, I want it to show certain demographic information regarding that specific location (population, household income, households, growth, etc - in radiuses of 1,3, and 5 miles).

Thank you for taking the time to review and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Demographic layer in Google Maps JavaScript API was deprecated and removed some time ago. If you check the release notes, you will see the following message

> **17 March 2015**
>
> Fixed:
>
> Issue 7756: Bug: Safari 8 performance regression
>
> **Removed demographics layer**
>
> Improvements to InfoWindow chrome

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases